# How to return IDs from T1 that have matches in 2/3 tables ONLY?

Tags: mysql, sql

4 TABLES:

**PARROTS**
ID(int)

**RED**
PID(int)

**BLUE**
PID(int)

**YELLOW**
PID(int)

I need to return all IDs from PARROTS table that have matching IDs-PID in RED and BLUE tables **ONLY**.

I tried this:

SELECT parrots.id,
FROM parrots JOIN red
ON parrots.id=red.pid
...

But I have no idea how change or extend this and make it return IDs that have matches in 2 tables (RED & BLUE tables) with PID, (if in 3 tables - don't need to be returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer join to find out about the absence of matching rows on a table (yellow table in this case). To find out about the presence an inner join will do the job naturally.

For example:

```
select p.*
from parrots p
join red r on r.pid = p.id
join blue b on b.pid = p.id
left join yellow y on y.pid = p.id
where y.pid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM PARROTS
WHERE ID IN (SELECT PID FROM RED UNION SELECT PID FROM BLUE)
```

If you need to exclude those that are present in YELLOW add

```sql
  AND ID NOT (SELECT PID FROM YELLOW)
```